# How do we obtain the following: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln{n^n}}{\ln{n!!}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln{n^n}-\ln(n-2)^{n-2}}{\ln{n!!}-\ln(n-2)!!}$

Tags: limits, factorial, limits-without-lhopital

I saw the following equality in an informal proof:

> $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln{n^n}}{\ln{n!!}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln{n^n}-\ln(n-2)^{n-2}}{\ln{n!!}-\ln(n-2)!!}$

I did not understand it and would appreciate clarification on how it is obtained.  Above is the exact notation used; I cannot help with any ambiguities about whether it is $\ln({n!!})$ or $\ln(n)!!$ although I believe it is the former.  (I suppose a numerical would help figure out which is meant but I am on mobile)

Update:  I would think the one who gave this proof surmised that $\lim{\ln(n-2)^{n-2}}+\ln{n^n}= \ln{n^n}$ because of the $n-2$ power, but I do not see how the expression in the denominator arises.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that $\ln(n)!!$ is not what is meant, as that is not really defined (ok, you can define it in terms of the Gamma function but the other option seems a lot more logical)

Comment: The rhs looks like a derivative. What about L'Hospital rule ?

Answer (score 1):

Some asymptotic estimates
for the double factorial
using Stirling.

$n!!
=\prod_{j=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} (n-2j)
$.

$\begin{array}\\
(2n)!!
&=\prod_{j=0}^{\lfloor (2n-1)/2 \rfloor} (2n-2j)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} 2(n-j)\\
&=2^n\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (n-j)\\
&=2^nn!\\
&\approx 2^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi n}(\dfrac{2n}{e})^n\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
(2n+1)!!
&=\prod_{j=0}^{\lfloor (2n)/2 \rfloor} (2n+1-2j)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{n} (2(n-j)+1)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{n} (2j+1)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{n} (2j+1)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{n} (2j+1)\dfrac{\prod_{j=1}^{n} (2j)}{\prod_{j=1}^{n} (2j)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=2}^{2n+1} j}{2^n n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!}\\
&=(2n+1)\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}\\
&\approx(2n+1)\dfrac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\dfrac{(2n)^{2n}}{e^{2n}}}{2^n \sqrt{2\pi n}\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}}\\
&=(2n+1)\dfrac{\sqrt{2}(2n)^{2n}}{2^n e^{2n}\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}}\\
&=(2n+1)\dfrac{\sqrt{2}2^nn^n}{ e^{n}}\\
\end{array}
$

If $n$ is even then
$n!!
\approx \sqrt{\pi n}(n/e)^{n/2}
$.

If $n$ is odd then,
putting $(n-1)/2$
for $n$,

$\begin{array}\\
n!!
&\approx n\sqrt{2}((n-1)/e)^{(n-1)/2}\\
&= n\sqrt{2}\sqrt{e/(n-1)}((n-1)/e)^{n/2}\\
&= n\sqrt{2}\sqrt{e/(n-1)}(n(1-1/n)/e)^{n/2}\\
&= \sqrt{2en^2/(n-1)}(n/e)^{n/2}(1-1/n)^{n/2}\\
&\approx \sqrt{2en}(n/e)^{n/2}e^{-1/2}\\
&\approx \sqrt{2n}(n/e)^{n/2}\\
\end{array}
$